# Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

Tags: java, android, manifest

Error: AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag

I just wanted to create new file .xml in drawable and miskcliked some how and wrote a .xm; and after that shit happend i had this error on all my projects.I created a new project and same eroor i've got.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuD3e.png)

All .xml files become a grey.I'll try to rebild sync with gradle and nothing helping me.I just a beginner so I'll hope you will help me

Comment: Why is `HomeActivity` detected as having error? What description AndroidStudio provides?

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

Comment: What is in `drawable` folder?

Comment: My icons and etc I have same error even I create a new project

Answer (score 0):

remove line 1 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: doesn't helped  Any thoughts?

Comment: How? This is just E:/prototype

Comment: Link to my project can you watch what's wrong [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZCpfv9RtBjWbmDmdxafro_75_7XFWwTy/view?usp=sharing)